# Forms between Django Client and Django Piston API

Tags: python, django, rest, django-forms, django-piston

Is there any easy way to process the ModalForm in Django Piston API to a Django Client? ,

On documentations @validate decorator is mentioning but I couldn't find the way to send forms from API to the Django Client. I feel like it is possible to use Django Forms from API like in local on Client side.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to render a form that represents a piston API endpoint, or if it's possible to use a standard Form POST to a piston API?

Comment: Yes, that's what i am trying to do.

Comment: er, I'm asking you to choose one or the other. "is it possible to render a form that represents a piston API endpoint" **OR** "is it possible to use a standard Form POST to a piston API?"

Answer (score 0):

Use Django Tastypie, it's a much more robust REST framework than Piston :)